# How to ignore/overwrite setters in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a Requests response object, *r*. *r* gets passed into a callback function as an argument. I want to perform an action on *r.text*, and then return the full *r* object.

However, when I try to reassign *r.text*,

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

is thrown

Answer (score 1):

The `text` attribute is a `propery` without setter.
If you want to modify it, you should copy it to a new variable like this:

```
from copy import copy
my_text = copy(r.text)
```

Comment: I need to REPLACE r.text with something else.

Comment: I think you shouldn't do it, the r.text is excepted from request, not anything else. If you want some change, you should assign `text` to a new object, and do with that.

Comment: im just going to assign it to r.text2 but im gonna leave the question open because there has to be an actual solution.

Comment: @user6769219 the property without setter means it is readonly, it must be design for purpose. So I don't think it is a good way to overwrite a readonly property to be writeable. There are many other way to avoid this, such as assigning it to `r.text2` like what you have done.